# 3D animated grease pencil brush stroke

Tags: grease-pencil

I've been working in AE with a paint brush line that animates on and winds between objects in the frame.

I've been liking the paint brush looks in grease pencil a lot better than I've been able to create in AE but I want to be able to have the line following a path that's properly 3D, rather than on a rotated flat plane.

So is there an easy way to paint or edit a stroke in grease pencil that follows such a 3D path? When I edit a paint stroke it has so many control points that it's very fiddly to move them about. If I simplify the curve I never get it back to how it was. I thought I'd be able to apply an arty brush effect to a curve, but I can't keep all the stylus pressure settings if I do that.

Many thanks. John

Answer (score 0):

I was just unfamiliar with the interface. In *Edit Mode*, I found if I activate the *Curve Editing* button, my paint stroke has fewer points and they have ease handles as well.